# Python: How to convert column with dictionary into columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a DataFrame with a column that contains a dictionary as follows:

```
df:
    date                                     dictionary
0   2021-01-01 00:00:00 + 00:00              'Total':{'USD':100, 'size':20}, 'country':{'USA': {'income': 20000}, 'fees': {'total': 55}}
1   2021-01-01 00:00:00 + 00:00              'Total':{'EUR':200, 'size':40}, 'country':{'France': {'income': 10000}, 'fees': {'total': 30}}
1   2021-01-02 00:00:00 + 00:00              'Total':{'GBP':100, 'size':30}, 'country':{'UK': {'income': 23000}, 'fees': {'total': 24}}
```

What I want is to set `USA` as a column name and take the value of `total` from the `fees` and set that as the value, to get the following:

```
df_final:
        date                             USA      France     UK
0       2021-01-01 00:00:00 + 00:00       55          30    NaN
1       2021-01-02 00:00:00 + 00:00      NaN         NaN     24
```

My DataFrame has hundreds of columns. I have tried the following:

```
df_list = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for dct in row['dictionary']:
        dct['date'] = row['date']
        df_list.append(dct)
```

But I get the following error: `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`. This happened specifically at `dct['date']`.

How can this be done?

EDIT: I added a few more rows to my DataFrame to better represent my problem.

Comment: dictionary column doesn't really look like dictionary, you're missing most outer wavy brackets. Is it just a string, you wish to parse into dict ?

Comment: What if you have another country in the column ? How do you want to display ?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski You are right, it is an object. I want to be able to get the `country` out of each entry and have the `total` from the `fees`. To be clear there are countries other than USA in my data

Comment: @Psidom, there are more countries in my data. I want each country to be a column name and the associated fees as the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)**

The first possibility I see, is if your dataframe contains valid json strings like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': [
        '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 
        '2021-01-01 00:00:00',
        '2021-01-02 00:00:00', 
    ],
    'dictionary': [ 
        '{"Total":{"USD":100, "size":20}, "country":{"USA": {"income": 20000}, "fees": {"total": 55}}}',
        '{"Total":{"EUR":200, "size":40}, "country":{"France": {"income": 10000}, "fees": {"total": 30}}}',
        '{"Total":{"GBP":100, "size":30}, "country":{"UK": {"income": 23000}, "fees": {"total": 24}}}',
    ]
})

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df
```

[image]

Then you could do:

```
import json

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    dict = json.loads(row.dictionary)
    dict_keys = list(dict["country"].keys())
    df.loc[idx, dict_keys[0]] = dict["country"]["fees"]["total"]

df_final = df.groupby(df.date.dt.date) \
    .agg('first') \
    .drop(columns=['date', 'dictionary']) \
    .reset_index()
    
df_final
```

[image]

**2)**

The second is if your df contained valid dictionaries like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': [
        '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 
        '2021-01-01 00:00:00',
        '2021-01-02 00:00:00', 
    ],
    'dictionary': [ 
        {"Total":{"USD":100, "size":20}, "country":{"USA": {"income": 20000}, "fees": {"total": 55}}},
        {"Total":{"EUR":200, "size":40}, "country":{"France": {"income": 10000}, "fees": {"total": 30}}},
        {"Total":{"GBP":100, "size":30}, "country":{"UK": {"income": 23000}, "fees": {"total": 24}}},
    ]
})

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df
```

[image]

Then you would:

```
import json

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    dict = row.dictionary
    dict_keys = list(dict["country"].keys())
    df.loc[idx, dict_keys[0]] = dict["country"]["fees"]["total"]
    # df.loc[index, row]

df_final = df.groupby(df.date.dt.date) \
    .agg('first') \
    .drop(columns=['date', 'dictionary']) \
    .reset_index()

df_final
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
aux = pd.json_normalize(df.dictionary, sep='_')
(aux.filter(like='income').loc[0]
 .index.str.extract(r'.*_(.*)_.*').join(aux['country_fees_total']).join(df)
 .pivot(index='date', columns=0, values='country_fees_total').reset_index()
 .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
                          date  France    UK   USA
0  2021-01-01 00:00:00 + 00:00    30.0   NaN  55.0
1  2021-01-02 00:00:00 + 00:00     NaN  24.0   NaN
```

Comment: This looks right, however I have many other countries in different rows. What I was hoping for is an automated solution without hardcoding

Comment: So, I would suggest you to fully describe the problem and the expected output, so that we can help you, @MathMan99.

Comment: I've edited my problem. Please let me know if it makes better sense now